# missing .lib files while compiling qt 4.8 project

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, mingw, qt-creator

I'm trying to build Open-Sankoré project (https://github.com/Sankore/Sankore-3.1) on qt-creator using qt 4.8.6 kit & mingw4 on windows..

I was able to overcome many compiler errors subsequently through some workarounds but this error stumped me:

```
    g++: ole32.lib: No such file or directory
    g++: oleaut32.lib: No such file or directory
    g++: user32.lib: No such file or directory
    g++: gdi32.lib: No such file or directory
    g++: advapi32.lib: No such file or directory
```

I guess it's related to msvc compiler and that I'm compiling now using gcc..

Anyone have an idea how to fix this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g++ cannot use .lib generated by msvc, is use libXXX.a lib files

download Qt for mingw g++

http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.7/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482-4.8.7.exe

Comment: To what the above .lib files belong ?  Qt framework ?

Comment: @GamalMohamed Mohamed yes and no, it belongs to qt framework for msvc , but not mingw g++